# How to replace a part of the word using sed command

Tags: linux, awk, sed, search, replace

I have a file with just one word in each line. I want to delete some part of the word in each line. How can I delete that part using sed command?
Ex:

```
u_fox/u_snake/u_snail/u_plus/u_core/u_vector/u_divider_rad4_0_1/instanceFE_OFC209016_vx0_srcb_fdivsqrt_44(code0_lo6_poic_hpc_int3_vcell05p00)
```

I want to delete this part : `(code0_lo6_poic_hpc_int3_vcell05p00)`, basically anything inside the brackets including the brackets.

All other lines in the file follow a similar pattern.

Comment: Is it possible that there might be text _after_ that final `)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/(.*)//' file
```

This is delete the string beginning with `(`, for any number of characters (denoted by the dot (`.*`), ending in `)`. This will happen on every line has this sequence.

Comment: Shorter: `s/(.*//`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -d'(' -f1 file
u_fox/u_snake/u_snail/u_plus/u_core/u_vector/u_divider_rad4_0_1/instanceFE_OFC209016_vx0_srcb_fdivsqrt_44
```

Answer (score -1):

With grep:

```
grep -o '^[^(]*' file
```

With column:

```
column -ts'(' -H2 file
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Below mentioned Awk command will do


awk -F "(" '{print $1}' filename   ==========>This will display output

awk -F "(" '{print $1}' filename >tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename  ======> If you want to save output in exsisting file
```

Comment: Please let me know reason for down vote

Comment: The question and all answers got downvoted.